# Warning: Undefined array key "datos"

Tags: php, session

Estoy estudiando y practicando PHP. Cree un formulario de login, en el cual el usuario se loguea y lo envia al index.php.

El usuario ingresa sus credenciales correo y contraseña e ingresa con éxito; de este modo quiero ayudar al usuario a que recuerde el correo y contraseña por medio de cookies y me arroja el error de que "datos" no está definida.

He analizado el código por bastante tiempo y no veo el erro, Por eso acudo a ustedes, que tienen experiencia y me guíen.

adjunto código.
Tanto el html como php se encuentran un mismo archivo que llame login.php

```
<?php
require "php/conex.php";

if (isset($_POST['correo'])) {

    $correo = $_POST['correo'];
    $password = $_POST['password'];
    $clave = hash_hmac('sha512', $password, 'keySecret');
    $recordar = $_POST['recordar'];
    // recordar contraseña
    $nombre = "datos";
    $valor = $correo."|".$password;
    if ($recordar=="on") {
        $fecha = time() + (60*60*24*7);
    } else {
        $fecha = time() -1;
    }
    setcookie($nombre, $valor, $fecha);
    // Query BD
    $sql = "SELECT * FROM users WHERE correo = '".$correo."' AND password_user='".$clave."'";
    $r = mysqli_query($conex, $sql);
    $n = mysqli_num_rows($r);
    // Clave y usuario
    if ($n==1) {
        // Los datos se pasan a un objeto
        $usuario = mysqli_fetch_assoc($r);
        // Inica Session
        session_start();
        // Variable de session
        $_SESSION['usuario'] = $usuario;
        // Se envia al index.php
        header("location:index.php");
    } else {
        $error = "Contraseña o Correo electrónico incorrecto.";
    }
}
$datos = $_COOKIE['datos'];
$correo = '';
$password = '';
if (isset($datos)) {
    $aDatos = explode('|', $datos);
    $correo = $aDatos[0];
    $password = $aDatos[1];
}
?>

<h2>Ingresar</h2>

<?php                                                    
                                                        
    if (isset($error)) {
        echo '<div class="alert alert-danger">';
        echo '<strong>* '.$error.'</strong>';
        echo '</div>';
    }
?>
<form action="login.php" method="post" class="login">

    <p class="before-login-text">¡Bienvenido de nuevo! Inicia sesión.</p>

    <p class="form-row form-row-wide">
        <label for="username">Ingresa dirección de correo electrónico<span class="required">*</span></label>
        <input type="email" class="input-text" name="correo" id="correo"
            value="<?php if(isset($correo)) echo $correo ?>" />
    </p>

    <p class="form-row form-row-wide">
        <label for="password">Ingresa la contraseña<span class="required">*</span></label>
        <input type="password" class="input-text" name="password" id="password" />
    </p>

    <p class="form-row">
        <input class="button" type="submit" value="Ingresar" name="login">
        <label for="rememberme" class="inline"><input name="rememberme" type="checkbox" id="rememberme"
                value="forever" /> Recordar</label>
    </p>

    <p class="form-row">
        <a href="recuperar-password.php" class="btn btn-outline-success">¿Olvidó la contraseña?</a>
        <a href="mi-cuenta.php" class="btn btn-outline-success">¿No tienes cuenta?</a>
    </p>

</form>
```

Agradezco de antemano a la persona que me ayude o explique el fallo que tengo.

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Comment: no tienes ninguna propiedad llamada "datos" dentro de $_COOKIE

Comment: Como dice @TrinidadMiranda, creo que sería correcto verificar primero si la `cookie` `datos` existe. Para ello podrías utilizar `isset()`

Comment: ¿Para que guardas los datos necesarios para autenticar al usuario en la cookie?. 
Y ya que estamos, sería conveniente que utilices [sentencias preparadas](https://www.php.net/manual/es/mysqli.quickstart.prepared-statements.php).

Comment: Gracias a los tres por responder, muy amables.